# Выпадающий список с деревом категорий

Tags: дерево, php

Вот здесь: http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=71&topic=4385 реализован один из способов как вывести дерево категорий через ul-li.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это дерево встроить в выпадающий список через select - option

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".prefix."_zboard_cat ORDER BY id");
$cats = getCats($res);

$pvars['vars'] = array (
'catz' => getTree($cats),
);

function getCats($res){

    $levels = array();
    $tree = array();
    $cur = array();

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

        $cur = &$levels[$rows['id']];
        $cur['parent_id'] = $rows['parent_id'];
        $cur['cat_name'] = $rows['cat_name'];

        if($rows['parent_id'] == 0){
            $tree[$rows['id']] = &$cur;
        }
        else{
            $levels[$rows['parent_id']]['children'][$rows['id']] = &$cur;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

function getTree($arr, $flg, $l){
$flg;
$out = '';
$ft = '-';
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){

if($k==$flg) { $out .= '<option value="'.$k.'" selected>'.str_repeat($ft, $l).$v['cat_name'].'</option>'; }
else { $out .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.str_repeat($ft, $l).$v['cat_name'].'</option>'; }
    if(!empty($v['children'])){     
        $l = $l + 1;
        $out .= getTree($v['children'], $flg, $l);
        $l = $l - 1;
    }
}
return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теге `select` `option`-элементы не могут быть вложенными.

Как вариант решения, выстраивать `option`-элементы в один уровень, а видимой древовидности добиваться с помощью пробельных отступов согласно уровню вложенности элемента в дереве.

Comment: Это понятно. Именно это и имелось в виду, что нужны либо отступы из пробелов или отделять уровни через дефис "-".

Comment: А что именно тогда непонятно?

Comment: Допустим не получается отладить код (добавил вопрос). Символ "-" выступает в качестве символа, который визуально увеличивает вложенность, но по каким-то причинам она не увеличивается.

Comment: Можно добавить в `getTree()` параметр `$level`. При рекурсивном спуске делать `+1`.

    function getTree(..., $level){
        getTree(..., $level + 1);
    }
    getTree(..., 0);

Comment: Спасибо. Наталкнули на правильную идею! Получилось вот что.

function getTree($arr, $flg, $l){
    $flg;
    $out = '';
    $ft = '-';
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){

 if($k==$flg) { $out .= '<option value="'.$k.'" selected>'.str_repeat($ft, $l).$v['cat_name'].'</option>'; }
 else { $out .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.str_repeat($ft, $l).$v['cat_name'].'</option>'; }
        if(!empty($v['children'])){  
   $l = $l + 1;
            $out .= getTree($v['children'], $flg, $l);
            $l = $l - 1;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

Comment: Вместо:

    $l = $l + 1;
    $out .= getTree($v['children'], $flg, $l);
    $l = $l - 1;

можно просто:

    $out .= getTree($v['children'], $flg, $l + 1);

Comment: Спасибо все работает! Еще раз Спасибо за своевременный ответ!

Comment: подскажите а как зделать? 
есть форма для редактирования с оным кол..полей
если автор не заполнил одно из обязательных полей в форме то он возвращается обратно к всей форме ...и все данные заполненные у него остаются а вот выбранная категория нет .... помогите правильно вернуть выбранную категорию ?
подозреваю где то здесь надо править
if($k==$flg) { $out .= '<option value="'.$k.'" selected>'.str_repeat($ft, $l).$v['cat_name'].'</option>'; }
 но чет у меня пока не получилось..

Помогите найти решения!?

Comment: да здесь сделал так    
function getTree($arr, $flg = 0, $l = 0)

а то чет в коде страницы ошибки были и пути к скрипту....